# Does Superman have any "normal" academic/professional/military achievements?

Tags: dc, superman

Has Superman ever been awarded any kind of official certifications or recognition of achievements from Earth?

I'm thinking about things such as honorary degrees from colleges, professional certifications, or even military awards or honors.

Comment: Doesn't he have like a hundred keys to the city of metropolis? Does that count?

Comment: I think he played college/highschool football... well, what passes for "football" when Americans throw non-round non-ball with their hands. In American cultural tradition, that's an important achievement :)

Comment: sort-of, but those aren't quite as "official" as I was looking for, since that's more of a PR stunt than anything. I'm looking for things that might give him the right to some initials after his name :)

Comment: Superman would give such a good commencement speech if he got an honorary degree

Comment: @Michael - as Superman, or as Clark Kent?

Comment: In some continuities, Clark has a Pulitzer, I think.

Comment: @DVK I'd take either.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YPWnG.png

Comment: "Initials after his name"...  Now I want to see an issue titled: Superman D.D.S.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - not much of a challenge for someone with heat vision rays

Comment: @DVK heat vision?  What has your dentist been doing to you?  You might want to go to a different one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Academics:***

- Silver Age Superman had a Journalism degree (presumably, Bachelors, but never specified for sure). Obviously, as Clark Kent.
- To the best of my (or Google's :) knowledge, he never was awarded any *Honoris Causa* degrees

---

---

***Professional***

From Wikipedia (sourced from *Moore,, John Francis (1994). Under a Yellow Sun, a novel by Clark Kent. DC Comics.*)

> - Modern Age retroactive continuity
>     In the wake of John Byrne's reboot of Superman continuity in The Man of Steel, many traditional aspects of Clark Kent were dropped in favor of giving him a more aggressive and extroverted personality (although not as strong as Lois's), including such aspects as **making Clark a top football player in high school** along with **being a successful author and Pulitzer Prize-winning writer**, which includes at least two original novels, The Janus Contract, and Under a Yellow Sun

---

---

***Civic:***

Shamelessly ripped off from http://forums.superherohype.com/showthread.php?t=369173&page=5:

> - In the comics was awarded Metropolis's Outstanding Citizen Award in Superman #93 (1954) "Jimmy Olsen's Double."
> - It is revealed that Superman was awarded honorary citizenship in all of the countries in the United Nations in Superman #146 (1961) "The Story of Superman's Life."
> - It is revealed in Action Comics #285 (1962) "The World's Greatest Heroine!" that Superman was awarded a special golden certificate by the United Nations giving him with the legal authority to apprehend criminals in U.N. member nations.
> - The key to the city has been awarded to Superman by the mayor of Metropolis (Action Comics #328 (1965) "Superman's Hands of Doom").

---

---

***Civic in honor of Superman***

> - Metropolis celebrates Superman Day (as seen in Superman #157 (1962) "Superman's Day of Doom", Action Comics #328 (1965) "Superman's Hands of Doom" and Action Comics #594 (1987) "All that Glisters").
> - Two commemorative stamps have been issued in Superman's honor, one by the U.S. Government in Superman #91 (1954) "The Superman Stamp!" and the other by the city of Rangoon, Burma in Superman #153 (1962) "The Secret of the Superman Stamp!"

---

---

**Military**:

- Superman has held the rank of General in the U.S. Army in Superman #133 (1959) "Superman Joins the Army!"

Comment: I also wasn't able to find any evidence of military honours/medals so far.